# Replace value until different value comes pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

My data is

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,0,0,0,2,0,0,3]})
```

Now, data output is

```
   a
0  1
1  0
2  0
3  0
4  2
5  0
6  0
7  3
```

I want 0 replace the count number like

```
   a new
0  1  1
1  0  1
2  0  1
3  0  1
4  2  2
5  0  2
6  0  2
7  3  3
```

Replace value as counting number until different count come.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please use correct upper case letters next time. Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 3):

You can [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
data['new'] = data['a'].mask(data['a'].eq(0)).ffill(downcast='infer')
```

output:

```
   a  new
0  1    1
1  0    1
2  0    1
3  0    1
4  2    2
5  0    2
6  0    2
7  3    3
```

Alternative **if the non-zero values are always increasing**, use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html):

```
data['new'] = data['a'].cummax()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
df.loc[df['a'].ne(0), 'new'] = df['a']
df['new'] = df['new'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

O/P:

```
   a  new
0  1  1.0
1  0  1.0
2  0  1.0
3  0  1.0
4  2  2.0
5  0  2.0
6  0  2.0
7  3  3.0
```

Explanation:

1. Mask 0 values and apply original value ('a')
2. Fillna with forward filling